# Wearing a toupee

Tags: hair, kippa-yarmulka, handicap-disabled-impair

If one wears a toupee that covers approximately what a normal kippa would cover, does he also need to wear a kippa?

Does it depend on whether or not people know it's a toupee and not just his normal hair?

Comment: It sounds mamosh pashut that it counts either way, but no source.

Comment: @HachamGabriel: What do you mean by that?

Comment: [See my answer here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15334/1172) I think the same applies to this situation.

Comment: Duplicate of [wearing a hat instead of a kipah](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15219/wearing-a-hat-instead-of-a-kipah)

Comment: @: If you think that's the answer, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @msh210 Handicap??

Comment: @DoubleAA, well, I was thinking of creating a [tag:prosthetic] tag for the occasion and adding it to other questions, too, but realized that the other questions were tagged [tag:handicap-disabled-impair] (so that the new tag would be kinda redundant) and decided that that applies here, too, inasmuch as someone needing a toupee is impaired with respect to the growth of hair.

Comment: @msh210 I suppose `:)`

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=451&st=&pgnum=3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Mishna B'rura (2:12)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=12) writes that there are those who say that a toupee-wearer must wear a kippa on top of it because of *maris ayin*, but there are others who say it's not necessary.

In other words: technically, it is a valid head-covering. But since we are worried that people will think that the toupee is his real hair and that he is not wearing a head covering, some say that he must wear an additional (clearly visible) head covering above it. [See also [P'ri Megadim (EE 91:4)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41248&st=&pgnum=83).]

This would imply that if it is obvious that it is not his real hair (e.g. a clown wearing a rainbow wig), then an additional kippa is unnecessary. For practical issues, CYLOR.

Comment: Not if someone grew an Afro and then dyed it.  Then it would look like a rainbow wig!

Comment: HaRav Yaakov Kaminetzky in Emet LeYaakov holds the same way.

Answer (score -1):

A married woman need not add a Tichel over her Sheitl. Maaris Aiyen is probably not relevant because those that know the man know he has no hair & those that don't know him Maaris Aiyen doesn't apply. A bad hairpiece can cause a Chilul Hashem.

Comment: The reason behind wearing a sheitel and the reason behind wearing a kippa are different enough I’m not sure you can generalize from one to the other.

Comment: Or rather: Just like a man should wear an additional head covering over his toupee to avoid maris ayin, so to must a woman wear an additional head covering over her sheitel for the same reason.