# Maris Ayin when nobody knows you're Jewish

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, hair, kippa-yarmulka, marit-ayin

According to [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15807/489), wearing a toupee without a *kippa* on top may pose a problem of *maris ayin*.

My question is: Suppose the toupee-wearer has no distinctive Jewish features other than wearing a *kippa*. In this case then, nobody would know he was Jewish unless he is in an area where people know him. Suppose he's in an area where nobody knows him. Would it still be *maris ayin*? If so, why?

Comment: I realize you're not asking "should he?" but "would it qualify as marit ayin", but assuming that his Judaism won't come out seems risky.  He'll never make a bracha, order only coffee in a restaurant, disappear early on a winter Friday, etc?  These could all come up in the context of, say, going to a technical conference far from home.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I'm not necessarily talking about going through his whole life like that. Just let's say he wants to go to the park for a few hours with his toupee on but doesn't want to wear a *kippa* on top of it.

Comment: Yeah, I realize you don't mean always -- besides, in that case people would come to know him and the premise of the question wouldn't apply.  I'm just wondering whether you can really correctly predict that it won't come up somehow; I've sometimes been surprised by contexts where my Judaism came up with strangers.  (Example: at a conference where I ate only salads, a fellow attendee noticed and asked if I was a vegetarian.  I could have dodged, but it was easier to just say "no, kosher".  If I were the man in your question, would I, in that instance, have thought about the absent kipa?)

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate?

Comment: @AdamMosheh Of the other toupee question? How? that one doesn't address maris ayin at all.

Comment: @HodofHod - No, of something else. Can't remember which though.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14694/1059

Answer (score 5):

There is a gemara in Beitzah 9 that brings a shitta that "Afilu b'chadrei chadarim" even in the the innermost room maris ayin applies even when alone. The Rambam paskans like that in hilchos shabbas 22:20.The Shulchan Aruch OC 301:45 paskens like that as well.

Comment: IIRC, the acharonim debate the ramifications of this rule. I believe that the S'dei Chemed maintains that it only applies to things that Chazal specifically banned because of *maris ayin*, like almond milk with meat (I think that was one of their things). Other things that we say are assur because they fall into the ***generalization*** of *maris ayin* might not have this rule apply to them.

Comment: Just to Sam and Jake's exchange, Rabbi Jeremy Wieder, a Rosh Yeshiva at YU, explicitly applied the S'de Chemed's distinction le'maaseh in response to a question I asked of him.